# anti-ordered query results

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'd like to have a query return results in an order that is somewhat inside-out.   I have a table of customer orders and I'd like to retrieve the N oldest orders to work on but in such a was as to maximize the number of different customers being processed.   I'm describing it as "anti-ordered" because the sort order is such that things that would normally be next to each other are spread out as much as possible.

```
CREATE TABLE custorders (
  order_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  customer,
  data
);

INSERT INTO custorders VALUES 
  (1,'joe','xyz'),
  (2,'joe','abc'),
  (3,'joe','def'),
  (4,'sam','qwe'),
  (5,'sam','rty');
```

I can get the single oldest order for each customer with something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM custorders
WHERE order_id IN 
(
 SELECT MIN(order_id) FROM custorders GROUP BY customer
);
```

But I'm stuck trying to get the 2 oldest for each customer, or (what I really want) the 10 oldest orders across all customers that maximizes the number of different customers.  That is, if there are 20 customers, it would give 10 different customers, but if there were only 8 different customers all with multiple pending orders then 2 customers would show up multiple times in the result.

I am working in sqlite 3, so solutions using functions specific to other databases aren't helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. SQL can not do this.

In general SQL has no ability to compare data across rows, only within them.

You are trying collate data across rows (the two oldest, etc).

You can try tricks like `min(order_id) + 2` and things like that (find the `min` where all records are greater than the other `min`), but they are not extensible.

Sorry.

PS. sqllite may have some special function for this, but I am not familiar with it. My answer is for SQL in general.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. I haven't tested it though.The logic is to select only 2 records with lower value of order_id where MIN() would only return one value.

```
 SELECT * FROM custorders
    WHERE order_id IN 
    (
    SELECT order_id FROM custorders GROUP BY customer
    ORDER BY order_id ASC
    LIMIT 2
    )
    ;
```

Comment: Does sqllite have a `LIMIT` option?

Comment: @Ariel I am not sure my answer was for general SQL.

Comment: @Ariel Yes, I was going to answer before with a somewhat similar query, but couldn't get sqlfiddle to run with this laptop so couldn't test it.

Comment: @BishnuPaudel General SQL doesn't have `LIMIT`. `LIMIT` is a MySQL thing.

Answer (score 0):

Preface: This is untested (sorry, this laptop wasn't playing ball with sqlfiddle) but I think this might work for you:

```
select 
    out.customer,
    group_concat(
        select 
            a.order_id 
        from 
            custOrders a 
        where 
            a.customer=out.customer 
        order by 
            order_id asc 
        limit 2
    ) as outStanding
from
    custOrders out
limit 10
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLlite doesn't appear to support the TOP keyword.  Limit 10 in a subquery grouped by customer is likely going to give you 10 customers not the top 10 per customer.

Implement top yourself...

I'm adapting a mysql solution here, so anyone with sqllite experience that wants to clean this up, feel free.  Something like the following should work.

We need to map order_id so that we have consecutive values per customer.  We want to assign rowid automatically ordered by our customer then his order_id in ascending order so we get the oldest first.  rowid is a hidden field that will be assigned for us if we don't use a primary key.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp(
  order_id INTEGER,
  customer text,
  data text
) AS SELECT * FROM custorders ORDER BY customer, order_id ASC;
```

Now we have rowid to key off of to determine what our first 10 are for each customer

```
SELECT t1.* FROM temp AS t1 JOIN (
  SELECT customer, MIN(rowid) AS min FROM temp GROUP BY customer
) AS t2 ON t2.min + 10 < t1.rowid AND t2.customer = t1.customer;
```